# android: showing GoogleMap in Fragments without using MapActivity

Tags: android, google-maps

I looked and searched but don't see an answer but seen many commerical Android apps that can display Google Maps in fragments along with other fragments to display lists of items and other UI fragments.

I do not know if I need to use MapActivity for the whole app since I have a mix of fragments in addition to wanting to display google map in one of the fragments.

Its like this:

Fragment 1: displays Summary of User Settings
Fragment 2: displays the Google Map of user's location
Fragment 3: displays a list of items relevant to the user

I am using a Facebook-like menu UI to navigate among the Fragments.  I like to know here is.... 
Can I mixed these Fragments together without using MapsActivity.
If I do need to use MapsActivity, how do work it with the other fragments that displays other UI elements that doesn't use MapsActivity's functions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a know issue (http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15347), and there are some ways around it, but no 'official' way to use a MapFragment yet.

Comment: Awsome news from Google on this topic: https://twitter.com/androiddev/status/275672428284375040

Answer (score 0):

The new Google Maps API V2 for Android has just been released, which includes a MapFragment class, take a look:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/